# DataTable.DefaultView.Sort Doesn't Sort

Tags: c#, datatable, sorting

I am confused on DataTable.DefaultView.Sort. Here is the segment of the code I want to use it in.

```
actionLogDT.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";

foreach (CustomerService.ActionLogStartEndRow logRow in actionLogDT)
{
  // code here
}
```

The samples I have seen don't use the foreach loop and thus is confusing me on how to process this. It isn't sorting as I thought it should be.

I see that .DefaultView returns a view, and .Table gives a compile error.

Comment: what is your question/confusion? what compilation error are you getting?

Comment: When sorting on a date column, that column must be defined as a DateTime in the DataTable. Else it may be treated as a string and sorted in an unexpected order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to take a slightly different approach. [This post](http://forums.asp.net/p/425620/425629.aspx) was the closest I could find to get my code to work. Here is the working result:

```
actionLogDT.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";
DataView dv = actionLogDT.DefaultView;

foreach (DataRowView logRow in dv) { . . . }
```

From there I just have to cast the value back into it's proper type.

```
(string)logRow["Status"].ToString()
```

Comment: Cast is redundant... `.ToString()` should be enough.

Answer (score 35):

```
actionLogDT.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";

actionLogDT = actionLogDT.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed.  Get a table, sort it, and use it while it's sorted a certain way.

Comment: Slightly different scenario/symptoms for me, but the .toTable() solved this for me. Thanks.
In my case, I was applying the DefaultView.Sort expression just fine and seeing the sort take effect for DropDownList, but it wasn't taking effect for a DataGrid.
YMMV: The DataGrid we're applying this to is a very basic read-only table that does not provide dynamic sorting, etc.

Comment: I have ported code from vb.net (with DT.DefaultView.Sort) to c# asp-net core. In vb.net, the sort has worked without overwrite (.DefaultView.ToTable();). Your posting here did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Sorting the view won't change the sort order of the data in the table, just the order in the view. It should work if you do your `foreach` on the view instead, casting the row from the DataRowView back to your strongly typed row.

```
foreach (DataRowView logRowView in actionLogDT.DefaultView)
{
    CustomerService.ActionLogStartEndRow logRow = logRowView.Row as CustomerService.ActionLogStartEndRow;
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Doing that gives me an "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'ActionLogStartEndRow'." error.

Comment: Does `ActionLogStartEndRow` derive from DataRow?

Comment: @Jeromy - I am sure it does. I am using the .XSD data layer to accomplish all of this.

Comment: Basically the same casting error. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'ActionLogStartEndRow'.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to account for the strongly typed row. This should hopefully do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var logRow in actionLogDT.DefaultView.ToDataTable()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, Since it seemed like you wanted to loop through records, you can just loop through the `dataRowView` objects in the `DefaultView`.

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in table.DefaultView)
{
    string strValue = drv["ColumnName"].ToString();
    // its also worth mentioning that a DataRowView has a Row
    strValue = drv.Row["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
actionLogDT.DefaultView.Sort = "["+actionLogDT.Columns[0].ColumnName+"] asc";
```

Comment: I'll try that next time I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious: Why are you using the **DataRowView**?

i.e.

```
foreach (DataRow row in actionLogDT.Rows)
{
  Console.WriteLine(row["Status"]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Because the question was about sorting a datatable. To enumerate the sorted data you need to enumerate the view, not the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a datatable back then you can do something like:

```
var dv = actionLogDT.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "StartDate";

actionLogDT = dv.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, the code below was the best way for me to invoke the solution.  Just copy your `origtable` to a `DataView`, and then the dataview can be sorted with a simple `.sort` command, and then set a new table equal to the sorted view (of your original table).  Use the sorted table `dt`  for your processing thereafter.

```
Dim View1 As DataView = New DataView(origtable)
View1.Sort = "LastName"
Dim dt As DataTable = View1.ToTable
```