# Sorting the objects of a DataTable collection

Tags: c#, sorting

I fetch all tables from a database using

```
tables = Utility.DBConnection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
```

How do I bring the tables in a alphabetical sort order after?
I checked the `GetSchema`, there is no property to give any sort order.

I want to do later:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows) {}
```

But I want to have the tables sorted before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208548/datatable-defaultview-sort-doesnt-sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tables is a DataTable, you can use the [DataTable.DefaultView Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) to provide a sorted view into the data:

```
DataView view = tables.DefaultView;

view.Sort = "Name";

foreach (DataRowView row in view)
{
}
```

Comment: Worked as apsected after I get it how to use it. Thx.

Comment: This does not help if you're passing a common interface through application layers.   (e.g. if you've got a method expecting `DataSet` to be passed in and you need to change sort order for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

just make an array/list of tables copied from the collection in the dataset, and sort it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Utility.DBConnection.GetSchema returns, but this is probably very close to what you want:

```
var sortedTables = from table in tables
                   orderby table.TableName ascending
                   select table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sorted dictionary --

```
DataTable dtTables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
SortedDictionary<string, DataRow> dcSortedTables = new SortedDictionary<string, DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow table in dtTables.Rows) {
    string tableName = (string)table[2];
    dcSortedTables.Add(tableName, table);
}

// Loop through tables
foreach (DataRow table in dcSortedTables.Values) {
    // your stuff here
}
```