# How do I sort a datatable i've created in to ascending order of date using C#

Tags: c#, date, datatable

I'm learning C# to help with my day job as an RPA developer. So I've created a datatable with a DateTime type column and I'm trying to sort the table out in to ascending dates as I ultimately want to pull out the entry in the table that has a 'Receipt Number' beginning with 'E' of the newest date.

This is my code
DataTable Receipts = new DataTable();

```
        Receipts.Clear(); 
        Receipts.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        Receipts.DefaultView.Sort = "Date ";
        Receipts.Columns.Add("Receipt Data", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr = Receipts.NewRow(); 
        dr[0] = "10 January 2021"; 
        dr[1] = "Receipt number is E1039742083";
        Receipts.Rows.Add(dr); 
        dr = Receipts.NewRow(); 
        dr[0] = "11 January 2021"; 
        dr[1] = "Receipt number is not found";
        Receipts.Rows.Add(dr); 
        dr = Receipts.NewRow(); 
        dr[0] = "11 January 2021"; 
        dr[1] = "Receipt number is F1039742083";
        Receipts.Rows.Add(dr); 
        dr = Receipts.NewRow(); 
        dr[0] = "12 January 2021"; 
        dr[1] = "Receipt number is E1039742083";
        Receipts.Rows.Add(dr); 
        dr = Receipts.NewRow(); 
        dr[0] = "12 January 2021"; 
        dr[1] = "Receipt number is not found";
        Receipts.Rows.Add(dr); 
        Receipts.DefaultView.Sort = "Date ASC";
        foreach (DataRow datarow in Receipts.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in datarow.ItemArray)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        } }
```

but this line doesn't seem to work Receipts.DefaultView.Sort = "Date ASC"; when it runs in visual studio it always runs with oldest dates first

Any advice would be really appreciated

Thanks

Jordan

Comment: Have you tried .Sort = “Date”

Comment: I'd create an additional column to store the meaning of the 'E' reports - even if that column is hidden - because that key element is just part of a longer string and not even at the start of the string.  Also, `"10 January 2021"` is a string, not a date - to be sure the data is as expected, I'd create dates for the data column.  Use the cell/column formatting abilities to format the display

Comment: Add DateTime objects to the Rows: e.g., `receipts.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 10), "Receipt number is E1039742083");` (btw, you don't need all those `DataRow dr = Receipts.NewRow();` etc.). Then, the DefaultView determines how the data is presented, the DataTable itself is not affected. If you set your DataTable as the DataSource of some Control, the data will be presented sorted. Note that you're setting `Date ASC`, which will present the older date first. Set `DESC` to order by the newer date (most recent date first).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, my 'C#' colleague is going to help me go through them today but from looking now they make sense and I look forward to trying them

Answer (score 0):

```
Receipts.DefaultView.Sort = "Date ASC";
Receipts= Receipts.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Find it here - [DataTable.DefaultView.Sort Doesn't Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208548/datatable-defaultview-sort-doesnt-sort)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing, I will try your solution and read the article today